# What is meant by "similar" in this context related to the Taylor series of a function?

Tags: functions, taylor-expansion

Consider the [following remark](https://mml-book.github.io/book/mml-book.pdf#page=149) of derivative from the chapter named *Vector Calculus* from the test book titled **[Mathematics for Machine Learning](https://mml-book.github.io/book/mml-book.pdf)** by *Marc Peter Deisenroth et al.*

> In general, a Taylor polynomial of degree $n$ is an **approximation of a
> function**, which does not need to be a polynomial. The Taylor
> polynomial **is similar to $f$** in a neighborhood around $x_0$. However,
> a Taylor polynomial of degree $n$ is an exact representation of a
> polynomial $f$ of degree $k \le n$ since all derivatives $f(i), i > k$
> vanish.

I understood the first sentence, which is saying that the Taylor series is an approximation to the underlying function. But the second sentence is a saying that the Taylor series is **similar** to $f$ in the neighborhood of $x_0$.

What is meant by similar in this context? Are they talking about the similarity of curves in the graphical representation of the functions around $x_0$?

Answer (score 2):

The Taylor polynomial of $f$ around $x_0$ is similar in the sense that it shares the first few derivatives with $f$ at $x_0$---as in, the zeroth derivative (the value of the function), the first derivative, etc., up to the $n$th derivative (for a degree $n$ Taylor polynomial) of the Taylor polynomial and the function all coincide *at the point* $x_0$.

Which, as you say, means the graphs of the functions (in good conditions) look quite alike near $x_0$. For an example where these good conditions don't happen, consider $f(x) = e^{-x^{-2}}$ at $x_0 = 0$.